# Restricting program to run only one instance

Tags: c

Here's a simple "hello world" C program that takes 10 seconds to complete:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("hello World 1 \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(10);
    printf("hello World 2 \n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

How can I modify it so at most only one instance of this executable can run at any moment in time? I'm using Linux.

For example, assume the server crashes if more than one instance is run simultaneously, and we're trying to prevent this. I'd like to see one or more example(s) of different ways so I can run and verify on my system.

Also, is there a simple way to queue them so if I run the C executable twice in a row, the second one runs just after the first one completes?

Comment: typically you want an external watchdog/launcher to perform such service.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the comment. I think he meant it's another tool's job to do what you ask for.

Comment: something like http://mmonit.com/monit/ ?  But i think I misread your question - you aren't really interested in running a daemon?

Comment: I think monit would work, but I'm looking for something simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically you usually acquire a file lock, create a run time file of a given file name with the process PID as the contents at initialization time (In a UNIX system usually in `/var/run/`). Delete the file on exit.

If the file already exists during startup, then another instance is already running.

Comment: On a POSIX system, you'd use `open()` with options `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL`.  That'll check for the file's existence and create it if necessary as a single atomic operation.  If the open succeeds, you know with certainty that the file didn't exist already, so your program is the one that's allowed to run.  If the file exists already, the open will fail, so you know that another instance of the program is already running.

Comment: See: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/flocking.html, man fopen, etc.

Comment: See my answer for what I came up with, based on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we name our C program `hello.c`, and compile it using: `gcc -g hello.c -o hello.exe`. Now instead of running the executable directly, we create a bash script to run it instead. The bash script checks if a dummy lock file exists, indicating the C program is running. If this lock file doesn't exist, it creates one to let future calls to this bash script know that the C program is running. Here's the bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! -f dummy.file ];
then
    echo "File not found. Let's create one now, then run hello.exe."
    echo 'locked'> dummy.file
    ./hello.exe
else
    echo "File dummy.file exists, so hello.exe is not run."
fi
```

Now we just need to add some code to the C program above to have it delete the file at the end of it's program, as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    printf("hello World 1 \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(10);
    printf("hello World 2 \n");
    fflush(stdout);

    if (remove("dummy.file") == -1)
      perror("Error in deleting lock file");
 }
```

Very simple. Thanks to skjaidev for hinting at this solution (for which I'll give credit as the answer).

Comment: Since you don't use file locking, it is possible to have two (or more instances of your program running). It all depends on the timing, since the check for the existence of the file and creation of the file is not atomic in your code.